# Find four unknown catheti lengths from three configured hypotenuses

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given this configuration of right-angled triangles as pictured, with only the provided information available — that is, the complete dimensions of the lesser triangle plus the two hypotenuse lengths of the other triangles.

[image: Trio of configured triangles]

I need to be able to calculate formulaically the unknown dimensions for the other two triangles. I have a whole series of these configurations that have decimalised catheti and are not in neat proportions hence why I need to find the formulae.

Please help as I have spent quite a bit of time trying to work this out without any success.

As for my efforts I have little to show for my time spent on this problem.
I can see that there are orthogonal pairs of parallel lines comprising the catheti.
I can also see the simplistic formulae like, for example AF = AE + 200 and AE = AF - 200, but none of these formulae are calculable without further information (I think) or bring me to the values.
For my mind, if I could just find the formula for calculating the length of BE then everything else is solvable by way of the dashed rectangle.

**What is the length of BE?**

Comment: Write Pythagora's for right triangles $ABE$ and $ACF$ then you have two equations to solve for $AE,BE$.

Comment: Besides using the hypotenuse values given above for those triangles, what are the catheti values I should be using? I am not sure what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: Solve $\,AE^2+BE^2=AB^2, (AE+EF)^2+(BE+CD)^2=AC^2\,$ for $AE,BE$.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find the solution:

∠CBA = arccos(((AB² + BC² - AC²)/(2•AB•BC)) = 158.5221008351°

∠CBD = 26.8701104101°

∠DBE = 90°

∠EBA = ∠CBA - ∠CBD - ∠DBE = 41.6519904251°

**BE = AB•cos(∠EBA) = 185.5923415927**

To find the remaining side lengths use variations of @dxiv helpful answers to find the rest:

BE = DF

AE = √(AB² - BE²)

AF = 200 + AE

CF = CD + BE

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comments, this can be solved without trigonometry by using Pythagora's theorem for right triangles $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle ACF\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
AE^2+BE^2 &= AB^2
\\ (AE+EF)^2+(BE+CD)^2 &= AC^2
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Expanding the latter and using the former:

$$
\begin{align}
AC^2 &= AE^2+ 2\cdot AE\cdot EF + EF^2+BE^2+2\cdot BE\cdot CD + CD^2
\\ &= \underbrace{AE^2+BE^2}_{\displaystyle=\;AB^2}+EF^2 + CD^2+2\cdot BE\cdot CD+ 2\cdot AE\cdot EF 
\\ \implies\;\;\;\; 2\cdot AE \cdot EF&= AC^2-AB^2-CD^2-EF^2-2\cdot BE\cdot CD
\end{align}
$$

Substituting back into the first equation $AE^2+BE^2 = AB^2$ gives a quadratic in $BE\,$:

$$
\left(AC^2-AB^2-CD^2-EF^2-2\cdot BE\cdot CD\right)^2 + 4 \cdot BE^2 \cdot EF^2 = 4 \cdot AB^2 \cdot EF^2
$$

With $AB \approx 248.4, AC \approx 464.3, CD \approx 101.3, EF = 200$ the equation is (approximately):

$$
4 \cdot 200^2 \cdot BE^2 + \left(464.3^2-248.4^2-101.3^2-200^2 - 2 \cdot 101.3 \cdot BE\right)^2-4\cdot248.4^2\cdot 200^2=0
$$

The [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4+200%5E2+x%5E2+%2B+%28464.3%5E2+-+248.4%5E2+-+101.3%5E2+-+200%5E2+-+2+101.3+x%29%5E2+-+4+248.4%5E2+200%5E2+%3D+0) are $\,BE \approx 185.7\,$ and $\,BE \approx 23.1\,$ (which can be calculated with better accuracy by using the full precision of the given lengths).

The fact that there are *two* solutions indicates that the construction is not unique with just the given constraints. Indeed, the triangle $\triangle BCD$ is univocally determined by the lengths of its sides, but point $A$ is defined by its distances to $B$ and $C$, and there are *two* matching points $A$ which are the two intersections of the circles centered at $B$ with radius $BA \approx 248.4\,$, and respectively centered at $C$ with radius $CA\approx 464.3\,$.

Comment: For the life of me, @dxiv, I cannot fathom your algebraic solution. I am just not math savvy enough. All I know is that it works and I am indebted to you for that. As a follow-up query, if just the dimensions of △ACF were known instead of △BCD, by way of an algebraic formula how would you calculate BE please?

Comment: @Pytheorem If all you know is $\triangle ACF$ and length $AB$ then $B$ can lie anywhere on a circle around $A$, so that's not enough information to resolve the construction. If that's not what you meant you should ask a new question with all the necessary details.

Comment: Thanks @dviv, that is a suitable answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you once again, @dxiv. This is even more helpful to me. I just couldn’t make that link until you spelt it out. Much appreciated. It so happens that last night I found this same geometrical double point relationship.

[image: A and A₁]